# SQLAlchemy execute statement exits python without error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
stmt = insert(StoredCountTaskLineItem).values(
                [
                    dict(
                        id=line_item.id,
                        count_task_id=count_task.id,
                        expected=line_item.expected,
                        count=line_item.count,
                    )
                    for line_item in count_task.line_items
                ]
            )

stmt_set = dict(expected=stmt.excluded.expected, count=stmt.excluded.count)
            index_elements = [
                StoredCountTaskLineItem.id,
                StoredCountTaskLineItem.count_task_id,
            ]

stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
                index_elements=index_elements,
                set_=stmt_set,
            )
```

On big `insert` statements, the program crashes with the following message without a stack trace `7 Killed  python -m inventory_overview.main`. I believe it's related to a DB (Postgres 10.1) error that's not handled by Alchemy. Is there a way to debug this issue?

Comment: Is the size of data is less than available RAM size?

Comment: @shaikmoeed we don't know. Python raises stack trace errors for lack of RAM right?

Comment: Not sure in your case. But I have seen errors like this when there is lack of RAM.

Comment: So your process crashes without a stack trace due to a lack of RAM?

Comment: Yes, correct. I got just killed!

Comment: Batch commits to limit the memory consumed.